# MSWord Flakey When Launched

Tags: microsoft-word

When I just open MSWORD and pull directly from the program it opens any word document in any file folder.  The problem is when I go directly to file file amd try to launch the word doc it opens the program but doesn't bring up the contents of the document.

I leave the program open and go back to the same word doc within the file folder and double click and launch it opens the document up.

In order for me to launch any word doc from a file folder I must have MS Word open.

The same situation occurs when I launch a document from email, I must have MSWORD open

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest reinstalling Office cleanly and making sure it is patches to the latest service pack. This ought to fix the problems as well as close any glaring security holes in your system.

If this is a pirate verison of Office then it may have included malware (very easy to do) which is now interferring with your system. Don't be a cheapskate and pay the developers for their work.